# C# Fail to set DatagridComboboxCell value to null

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a datagridview in which there exists a combobox column, and this column is binded a list of options. My logic is that, if the user selects the wrong option, the program could detect and deselect this wrong option(which means comboboxCell.value = null).

The psuedo code for this logic is as follows:

```
//use CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged and CellValueChanged as event listeners 
this.DGV.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += DGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
this.DGV.CellValueChanged += DGV_CellValueChanged;

//CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event 
private void DGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DGV.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            DGV.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }

//CellValueChanged event
private void DGV_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CheckingCorrect(DGV.CurrentCell)) 
        {
          // set selected value null
          DGV.CurrentCell.Value = null
        }
    }
```

However, after the code sets currentcell value to null, the datagridview cell still kept the selected value shown.

I also tried may other ways like DGV.ClearSelection(), but none of these works.

Comment: you may want try other events, such as `CellBeginEdit`, `CellBeginEdit`, `CellValidating`, `DataError`.

Comment: How are you adding the items to the combo box cells? Do all the cells have the same value? Does a `null` value exists in the combo boxes list of items?

Comment: @JohnG I use datasource to bind data to combobox column: column.DataSource = souce.  null value does not exist in the combobox list of items. (I tried to add a "dummy item" as null value, and set value to this dummy item but still failed)

Comment: OK, so the combo box column uses a `DataSource`. Does that `DataSource` contain a `null` value? I am just saying that the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` doesn’t like to set its value to something that is not in its list of items… i.e., the `DataSource`. Also, it is not clear “when” you want to “change” this value... When the selection is made or when the user tries to leave the cell? Also, when would you “know” what values in the combo box are “invalid” and the combo box needs to be set to `null`?

Comment: Is what I am getting at is that if you “know” beforehand what “valid” items should be in the combo box, then it may be a better approach to NOT display any “invalid” items in the combo box. This would mean that each combo box “may” contain different values.

Comment: @JohnG the datasource only has items to choose, I tried to add a dummy item (which means it displays as "plz choose" but its value is actually nothing, which is exactly a null value) but it doesn't work either. My target is that, after the selection is made, I can get the selected object and determine if it is correct, if not, I will not show this option in the combobox.

Comment: The reason for me to design this mechanism is that, this combobox contains a list of design options(stored in database, has many design parameters) for designing a tunnel. I have to list all these design options to choose in order that I can check if these options obeys design rules, and then I can give the user suggestions (like, some parameters are too big or some too small) so that the user can go back to database, tuning these parameters, making the design options valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242838/discussion-between-johng-and-lake-lagunita).

Comment: Not sure I'd appreciate a program taking my painstakingly and slowly typed 1000 digits of Pi, and deciding that because I'd put a comma accidentally in the 275th char it should be erased to null. Try and preserve user input rather than destroy it on a whim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that will make working with the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn/Cell` easier...

1. > Make a Class specifically for the combo box column
2. > Use the proper event to help in casting the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` to a
   > regular `ComboBox`.

In this example I made a simple Class called `ComboValues` that has two properties for the column `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`. In this example the `ValueMember` is an `int`, however you could leave it out or use some other type that fits your needs. This class will simplify things as we will have the properties for both the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` for the combo box column.

This `ComboValues` Class may look something like…

```
public class ComboValues {
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

Then a method to get a `List<ComboValues>` from the DB that we will use as a `DataSource` for the combo box column.

```
private List<ComboValues> GetComboValues() {
  List<ComboValues> items = new List<ComboValues>();
  items.Add(new ComboValues { Value = 0, Display = null });
  items.Add(new ComboValues { Value = 1, Display = "Option 1" });
  items.Add(new ComboValues { Value = 2, Display = "Option 2" });
  items.Add(new ComboValues { Value = 3, Display = "Option 3" });
  items.Add(new ComboValues { Value = 4, Display = "Option 4" });
  return items;
}
```

And setting up the combo box column for the grid…

```
private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn GetComboCol() {
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  col.HeaderText = "Combo Items";
  col.ValueMember = "Value";
  col.DisplayMember = "Display";
  col.DataSource = GetComboValues();
  return col;
}
```

We will call the above method in the forms `Load` event to add the column to the Grid…

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DGV.Columns.Add(GetComboCol());
}
```

Next, we want to set up the edited `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` to act like a REGULAR `ComboBox`. We can do this using the grids `EditingControlShowing` event. This event will fire when the user clicks into a cell and in this case if the user clicks into a combo box cell, then we want to cast that cell to a globally defined `ComboBox`. So, we will need a global `ComboBox` variable called something like… `EditedComboBox`.

```
ComboBox EditedComboBox = null;
```

Is what we will do is that when the grids `EditingControlShowing` event fires and we check to see if it is the combo box cell, then we simply cast that cell to our global `EditedComboBox` and wire up its `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Then we can capture “when” the user “changes” a value in the combo box cell. The `EditingControlShowing` event may look something like…

```
private void DGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
  if (DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) {
    EditedComboBox = (ComboBox)e.Control;
    if (EditedComboBox != null) {
      EditedComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
  }
}
```

Above, column index 0 is the target combo box column. All we need to do is implement and wire up the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and wait for the user to change the combo box value.

When the user does indeed change the combo boxes value, then our `SelectedIndexChanged` event will fire and it is in this event where you would “CHECK” if the selected value needs adjustments on some parameters. In this example, the condition is if the user selects “Option 3”, then that is an invalid value and we will set the cells value to null. This event may look something like…

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //Debug.WriteLine("CB_SelectedIndexChanged");
  if (EditedComboBox != null) {
    ComboValues cv = (ComboValues)EditedComboBox.SelectedItem;
    if (cv != null && !CheckingCorrect(cv.Display)) {
      EditedComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
      EditedComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
      EditedComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);//DGV.CurrentCell.Value = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

In this event, we grab (cast) the combo boxes `SelectedItem` to a `ComboValues` object. With it we can easily check what value is selected and in turn set its value to null if needed. Note “item” 0 in our `List<ComboValues>` is the `null` value, so we set the combo boxes `SelectedIndex` to zero (0) to make the grid display a `null` value.

Also, since we are “changing” the combo boxes `Index`, we do NOT want this event to re-fire.

Lastly, we need one more event to wire up to TURN OFF the `SelectedIndex` changed event to prevent it from firing more than we want. In this case we will wire up the grids `CellLeave` event. In that event, the user is leaving the cell and if the `EditedComboBox` is not `null`... then we know we need to un-wire the event. It may look something like…

```
private void DGV_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (EditedComboBox != null) {
    EditedComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
    EditedComboBox = null;
  }
}
```

I altered the checking code to check for a `string` and not necessarily a cell. The condition checker code…

```
private bool CheckingCorrect(string cellValue) {
  if (cellValue != null && cellValue == "Option 3") {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps and makes sense. If you have questions, then feel free to ask.